# Insert data from user-defined table on some fields, other fields must use scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would I make use of my user-defined table that comes loaded with data, insert into a table but 1 of the table fields won't be using the data from the User Defined Table. I want a scalar variable to take its place.

`@dataTableType` is the following user-defined table:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[NewSequenceType] AS TABLE (
    [FK_Sequence] [int] NULL,
    [FK_Status] [int] NULL,
    [FK_Shift] [int] NULL,
    [PK_SequenceType] [int] NULL,
    [TypeName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [SequenceName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [SequenceDetails] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [SequenceStatus] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [SequenceShift] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [EquipmentId] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Comments] [varchar](512) NULL,
    [EnteredDate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spNewInspectionEntry] (@dataTableType NewSequenceType READONLY)
    INSERT INTO dbo.PIT_Inspection (FK_Sequence, FK_Status, FK_Shift, FK_EmployeeName, FK_EquipmentName, Comments, EnteredDate)
        SELECT 
            FK_Sequence, FK_Status, FK_Shift, EmployeeId, 
            EquipmentId, Comments, EnteredDate
        FROM 
            @dataTableType;
```

What I'm looking to do:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeIDExists varchar(8);
--Note that I only care about one row, this is Ok.
SELECT TOP 1 @EmployeeIDExists = EmployeeId FROM @dataTableType;

--Retrieve PKEmployeeId
SELECT @EmployeeIdPK = PK_EmployeeName
FROM dbo.PIT_EmployeeName
WHERE EmployeeId = @EmployeeIDExists

--Now I need to insert the value of @EmployeeIdPK? Along with the rest, it needs to replace EmployeeID and EquipmentId, Not sure how to...
INSERT INTO dbo.PIT_Inspection (FK_Sequence, FK_Status, FK_Shift, FK_EmployeeName, FK_EquipmentName, Comments, EnteredDate)
    SELECT 
        FK_Sequence, FK_Status, FK_Shift, EmployeeId, 
        EquipmentId, Comments, EnteredDate
    FROM 
        @dataTableType;
```

How can I get `@EmployeeIdPK` in Along with the rest, it needs to replace `EmployeeID`, I don't want the `EmployeeId` from the user-defined table to go there, I want the variable `@EmployeeIdPK` instead.

Comment: How many rows are in the TVP? If more than one, do you want that same value in that variable used for all rows? Regardless, have you tried just replacing the `EmployeeID` column in the SELECT with `@EmployeeIdPK`?

Comment: No i haven't figured it couldn't be that easy lol I will try that. Btw, there is always 18 rows in the TVP.

Comment: You should def provide an answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put any expression, variable, and literal value in the `SELECT` list. Just keep in mind that those values will be repeated for *all* rows.

Meaning:

```sql
SELECT Field1,
       Field2,
       'hello' AS [LiteralText],
       5 AS [LiteralNumber],
       @Variable AS [ValueFromVariable]
FROM TableName;
```

will repeated those literal and variable values for all rows.

Hence:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.PIT_Inspection (FK_Sequence, FK_Status, FK_Shift, FK_EmployeeName,
         FK_EquipmentName, Comments, EnteredDate)
    SELECT 
        FK_Sequence, FK_Status, FK_Shift, @EmployeeIdPK, 
        EquipmentId, Comments, EnteredDate
    FROM 
        @dataTableType;
```